# @Mod only has "value"

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm on my first minecraft. I followed the documentation until the creation of the `Main` class. There has to be `@Mod()` but I can only input `value. In the documentation it says there has to be modid etc.

```java
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;

@Mod(modid = "test")
public class Main {
}
```

The error is:

> Cannot resolve method 'modid'

The problem is strange. On github, the file has all those symbols but not on my machine. When I open the file (Mod.java) it only has „value“ but in the public forge fml repo it has all the fields

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the IDE or rebuild / clean the project